# What do you call the part of a metal structure that allows something to rotate endlessly in a 360 rotation?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Like in the picture above you can see that the lower part can rotate endlessly while the yellow thing allow the rest of the metallic parts to hang something and rotate endlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is generally called a *swivel*, and specifically, your image might be called a ["double-jaw clevis swivel shackle"](https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1SsfnloF7MKJjSZFLq6AMBVXac/224259114/HTB1SsfnloF7MKJjSZFLq6AMBVXac.jpg), if you want to be *exceedingly* specific.

A [*clevis*](https://www.playgroundequipment.com/image/cache/data/2017-Swing%20Parts/PCS005_Single_Clevis_Connector_Top_View_Catalog-1000x707.jpg) is a loop (*yoke)* closed by a through-bolt, or by a through-pin held with a bent back *cotter pin*. Oh, and *shackle* is a general term for a device to hold a rod-shaped object (e.g., the prisoner's legs were *shackled*), and *clevis* is a specific type of shackle.

Comment: See also: [Gimbal.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal)